# How can I add a this selector to selector with string

Tags: jquery, href, css-selectors

I know you can use the selector `$("a[href*= 'abc']")`
but is there any way to use the this selector?

```
$("a[href*= this ]")
```

Comment: need some more explanation.. why do you need to use `this` ??

Comment: `this` will return an element, doubt if it will be helpful for you to match it against the `href` attribute.

Comment: What is "the this selector"? "Selector" generally refers to CSS selectors, and there isn't a CSS selector called "this".

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2):

You can freely concatenate variables into the selector, since it's just a string like any other:

```
$("a[href*='"+somevar+"']")
```

However I doubt that `this` is what you want to use. Maybe something like `this.getAttribute("rel")` or something, but not `this` by itself.

Make sure you test with `console.log(your selector here)` to make sure you're passing the correct string to jQuery!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$("a[href*= '" + this.href + "' ]")
```

Comment: yes, I'm looking for an alternative for that selector.